# looking for an email application to manage multiple emails accounts

Tags: thunderbird, email

I am looking for an email application to access and use multiple email account at once. I know thunderbird can be used to access multiple email accounts but I am not sure if it selects the same account that an email was sent to while responding. For instance, if I use a gmail based account and zoho based account, if I reply to an email sent to zoho account which email will be used? ~ib

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Please ask one question at the time. Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/787196/edit) your current question to contain only the part if thunderbird can handle multiple-accounts while sending from one account or the other and open a new question for a alternative mail clients.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu on a laptop/desktop or Ubuntu Touch? I personally find Dekko good on Touch for accessing multiple accounts. If I get an email to the one accounts t I can change the sends in the reply to a different account.

Comment: @Phil Sorry for missing the detail. I was having pc based app in mind.

Comment: No worries at all. I cannot answer from the desktop version as I only use the web based email there. it is only on my Ubuntu tablet and Phone, I use Dekko.

Comment: @user3535991: as your question is still marked as unanswered: are you still searching? Is thunderbird not working for you? Please let us know if we can further help ;)

Comment: @dufte -- Yes! my question has been answered and however, I didnot get it to set it up yet. Will comeback to you if I face any issues. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @PhilUK - How is the ubuntu touch? I know this is a naive question Does it support most common apps (available on IOS or Android ?)

Comment: I must admit I like it on phone & especially on the tablet. A bit of adjustment, but worth it. Apps selection is not as vast as the others 2. What there is, some have issues & some just do not work correctly. However, the main apps that I need are available on Touch. I looked at all the apps I had on android and most I hardly ever used. I like the regular updates that keep improving this & by posting here it feels like I am making a difference. We have 2 Touch tablets & the Samsung tablet just has dust on it.

Comment: @user3535991 alright - feel free to accept the answer then if it answered your question completly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thunderbird can manage multiple accounts and therefor covers your task.

Regarding your question:

- Emails to foo@bar.com are replied using foo@bar.com
- Emails to blub@ueber.org are replied using blub@ueber.org

You can for sure define other reply-to addresses for each account if needed, but that isn't what you are asking for.

Thunderbird can as well handle several identities for a single account, which is another abstraction layer ;)

Comment: Yes, TB can handle several mailboxes, and several aliases per mail box, and will use the target alias/mailbox for the  "From" field (though there is a long standing bug of forgetting to do this when replying to a mailing list...). You can also override the From address to be any of your aliases in any of your mailboxes (and TB will send the mail throuhg the proper SMTP server). Another nicety is that you can drag/drop mails across mailboxes.

Comment: Thanks! Found this ! http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-set-up-mozilla-thunderbird-3-multiple-email/